# TensorType does not support iteration. Maybe you are using builtin.sum instead of theano.tensor.sum? (Maybe .max?)?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I try to train data based with a convolutional neural network,

```
    //Reshaping_data
    batch_size = 256
    nb_epoch = 50
    Nrb_filter= 64
    Filter_Size= 3
    print('Build model...')
    model = Sequential()
    input_traces = Input(shape=(nb_samples,))
    model.add(Conv1D(Nrb_filter, Filter_Size, activation='relu', 
    input_shape=input_traces))
    model.add(Conv1D(Nrb_filter, Filter_Size, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(Filter_Size))
    ...
```

The error that I have is:

```
Defining CNN  Model
Build model...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CNN_Based_Attack.py", line 136, in <module>
    model.add(Conv1D(Nrb_filter, Filter_Size, activation='relu', input_shape=input_traces))
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 88, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 330, in __init__
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 100, in __init__
    super(_Conv, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 299, in __init__
    batch_input_shape = (batch_size,) + tuple(kwargs['input_shape'])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/var.py", line 600, in __iter__
    raise TypeError(('TensorType does not support iteration. '
TypeError: TensorType does not support iteration. Maybe you are using builtin.sum instead of theano.tensor.sum? (Maybe .max?)
```

I really don't understand the error, and how to resolve ot, I would be very grateful if you could help me please?

Comment: You need to specify the values and types of all variables in your code, specially Nrb_filter and Filter_Size.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro  I have already specify all of them , could you please see the edited question?